# Passing looped variable to ansible role

Tags: variable, ansible

Is there a way to pass a list of values to /vars/main.yml file to subsequently pass those variables to the tasks for processing.

The intention here is to running the task once rather than N times.

My current `/vars/main.yml`

```
---
srv:
   httpd
   nginx
```

parses as `TASK [app : Install the httpd nginx server package] ************`
which is not liked by yum module.

```
---
    - name: Install the {{ srv }} server package
      yum:
        name: "{{ srv }}"
        state: present
    - name: Check for the installed package
      yum:
        list: "{{ srv }}"
      register: yumout
    - debug:
       var: yumout
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is... FIrst of all, your list of values in `srv` is not formatted with correct [ansible yaml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html). You need to indicate each with a `-`. Second, the tasks are calling "{{ srv }}" as if it was a single value, but it contains a list of values and it can't handle that. The way you iterate over a list contained in a variable is with `loop:`

Comment: I am trying to pass a list of values to the vars in role, this way i am willing to install multiple packages ( passed as variable ) in one go rather than running the playbook multiple times for different packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The playbook might look this way. I have not tested the code, it's just off the cuff...

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Install the {{ srv }} server package
    yum:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
    loop: "{{ srv }"
  - name: Check for the installed package
    yum:
      list: "{{ srv }}"
    loop: "{{ srv }"
    register: yumout
  - debug:
    msg: yumout
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example in the [documentation of the yum module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html):

```
- name: ensure a list of packages installed
  yum:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
  vars:
    packages:
    - httpd
    - httpd-tools
```

You only have to change the list in your `/vars/main.yml`:

```
---
srv:
  - httpd
  - nginx
```